# Apache Bench: Benchmarking tool HTTP/3 support

Tags: load-testing, apachebench, quic, http3

I have a Nginx 1.25.3 server configured to accept HTTP/3 QUIC connections in port 443.

While benchmarking using apache bench, the following output.

```
hari@hari-virtual-machine:~$ ab -n 100 -c 10 https://localhost/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1879490 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)...SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
..done


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            443
TLS Server Name:        localhost

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        0 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   0.036 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        50
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 0, Exceptions: 50)
Total transferred:      0 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    2743.94 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       3.644 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.364 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          0.00 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:     0    0   0.3      0       2
Waiting:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Total:          0    0   0.3      0       2

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      0
  66%      0
  75%      0
  80%      0
  90%      1
  95%      1
  98%      1
  99%      2
 100%      2 (longest request)
```

Indicating that it is not able to connect with it. When HTTP/2 (TCP) is also enabled, the same is successful. How to benchmark the QUIC server using Apache Bench?

Comment: Do you know if it even supports HTTP/3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ab`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) is a tool for testing [Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/) and this guy supports only [HTTP2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_http2.html)

As there is no support for HTTP3/QUIC in the main project the benchmarking utility doesn't support HTTP3 (yet?)

You will need either to look for an alternative tool like [quicbench](https://github.com/devsisters/quicbench) or go for [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) load testing tool. JMeter doesn't support HTTP3 per se but it's possible to use a client library like [kwik](https://github.com/ptrd/kwik) which can be used either from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) or you can come up with [your own JMeter Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development)

Comment: h2load from nghttp2 supports QUIC, and I plan to use it. Thanks.